# How to perform calculation based on the form value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, populate

I have this code

```
<form>

<input type = "number" name="name1" value="">

<input type = "number" name="name2" value="">

</form>
```

Here I want to display the 25% of value of **name1** on **name2** when user inputs the **name1** value. Please I need the javascript code to do this

let's assume the user inputs 100 in the first field and the 25% of 100 is 25, now the second field will update itself to 125 onchange.

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried to do to solve your issue? Even if you can't, you might be able to provide a better understanding on what you're trying to do to others.

Comment: let's assume the user inputs 100 in the first field and the 25% of 100 is 25, now the second field will update itself to 125 onchange.

Comment: So 125% of the value of `name1` or a 25% increase?

Comment: yes. it is increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a 25% increase you can do that easily with the JS

`document.querySelector('[name=name2]').value = this.value * 1.25`

It gets the input that has `name="name2"` and makes its value 125% of the value of name1

```html
<form>

<input type = "number" name="name1" value="" oninput="document.querySelector('[name=name2]').value = this.value * 1.25">

<input type = "number" name="name2" value="">

</form>
```

Comment: Your answer works but it prevent me from adding line break or div